# Embedding Maps from Kibana elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elk, kibana-7

lately, we have been using Kibana visualization in my site as iframes.
somehow the maps object are not "sharable"

is there a way to embed Kibana map object with its layers?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

the structure:

```
<iframe src="< map_url  >?embed=true&< my_filters >"/>
```

the URL from your Kibana while editing the map is long. 
URL ex:

```
http://localhost:5601/app/maps#/map/585eccc0-8333-11ea-aa91-b307cde3c7dc?_g=(filters:!(),refreshInterval:(pause:!f,value:0),time:(from:now-1y,to:now))&_a=(filters:!(),query:(language:kuery,query:''))
```

the part until the question mark is your map URL. 
map_url ex:
`http://localhost:5601/app/maps#/map/585eccc0-8333-11ea-aa91-b307cde3c7dc`
after the question mark there are some filters
my_filters  ex:
`g= refreshInterval%3A(pause%3A!t%2Cvalue%3A0)%2Ctime%3A(from%3Anow-1y%2Cto%3Anow))`

the end result:

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:5601/app/maps#/map/585eccc0-8333-11ea-aa91-b307cde3c7dc?
embed=true&_g= refreshInterval%3A(pause%3A!t%2Cvalue%3A0)%2Ctime%3A(from%3Anow-1y%2Cto%3Anow))
"height="600" width="800"/>
```

you are invited to 
context me for calrifications
good luck